# Convergence of integrals of function sequences evaluated by inequalities.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If the function sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty},\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty},\{h_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies
$$f_n\rightarrow f,\  g_n\rightarrow g,\  h_n\rightarrow h\ \text{a.e.}\ \ (f,g,h\in L^1(\mathbb{R})),$$
and
$$f_n\leq g_n\leq h_n,\ \ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx,\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}h_n(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}h(x)dx.$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_n(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions $g_n - f_n$ and $h_n - g_n$ are non-negative, hence we can apply fatou-lemma. Let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure. Then

$$   \int (g-f) d\lambda = \int \liminf(g_n - f_n) d\lambda \le \liminf \int g_n d\lambda - \liminf \int f_n d\lambda = \liminf \int g_n d\lambda - \int f d\lambda$$
And similarly
$$  \int (h-g)d\lambda = \int \liminf (h_n - g_n)d\lambda \le \int h d\lambda - \limsup \int g_n d\lambda $$
Where we used that if $a_n$ converges to $a$, then $\liminf(a_n - b_n) = a - \limsup b_n$ and $\liminf(b_n - a_n) = \liminf b_n - a$

Hence $$ \int g d\lambda \le \liminf \int g_n d\lambda $$ and $$ - \int g d\lambda \le - \limsup \int g_n d\lambda $$

Which gives us $$\int g d\lambda = \lim \int g_n d\lambda$$

If you want more probabilistic look at it, search for Pratt's lemma